# Why is the length R cosine theta?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Why is the [length described as R cosine theta (the top where the Sphere is sliced off)?](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m103/stretch.jpg) I've been staring at the geometry for quite a bit & can't figure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [SOHCAHTOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sohcahtoa#Mnemonics) (a special case of the [law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) that only works for right triangles), the cosine of an acute angle of a right triangle is the length of the leg adjacent to the angle, divided by the length of the hypotenuse. Equivalently, the length of a leg is the length of the hypotenuse times the cosine of the acute angle adjacent to the leg. In this case, the hypotenuse length is $R$ and the acute angle is $\theta$. Thus the length of the leg adjacent to $\theta$ is $R\cos\theta$.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to give you a point, but thanks.  I hope others do see this & give you a point.

Comment: No problem. You can still accept it if it answers your question (the check mark).

Comment: I always favored "COS is CLOSEST"